# Match by exported instance in Grafana and Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, re2, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm working in Grafana and Prometheus and I have Pushgateway exporting some stats for me. In Grafana, I am trying to display these results per machine. My jobs match an entire lab and the instance is related to the machine (ie. ab01:9100, ab02:9100 etc). I try to do '''avg(cpu_usage{exported_instance=~"$instance")'''
but that doesn't work and I suspect it is because the exported_instance is ab01 and the instance is ab01:9100. Is there a way for me to match this? Do I need to use a re2 regex?

Comment: Update: was able to use "$show_hostname" rather than "$instance" and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
avg(cpu_usage{exported_instance=~"${instance}.+")
```

Or something more specific, like:

```
avg(cpu_usage{exported_instance=~"${instance}:9100")
```